# Are questions about GitHub on topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, github

I just noticed that this question is closed:

[GitHub - List commits by author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174276/github-list-commits-by-author)

It's not obvious why it got closed, but I'd feel reasonably confident guessing that it's because the question is about using github.com, and this wasn't deemed programming-related enough. I don't imagine that a question asking how to perform the same task purely using Git would ever get closed.

Assuming that my guess is accurate, I don't agree with the closevoters' logic. GitHub, like Git, is a tool used by programmers, and so questions about it are within the scope of StackOverflow just as much as questions about IDEs or about Git are. The fact that GitHub also happens to be a website doesn't seem to me like a significant factor.

Am I missing something, or should the linked question be reopened?

Comment: I close voted that question because I don't think a website could be considered as a tool used by developers. If it is questions about msdn.microsoft.com or mdn.mozilla.org would become in scope which I find a very broad definition of a 'tool' used by a developer.

Comment: That seems off-topic to me also I would have done same !

Comment: @rene I find it hard to imagine a question anyone would want to ask about *how to use* MDN or MSDN, but if they had a (reasonable) question of that nature, I would consider it analogous to this case and wouldn't consider it off-topic.

Comment: @rene Even if you wouldn't agree with allowing questions about MDN or MSDN, though, there seems to be a clear difference in nature between those sites, which we use purely to read their content, and GitHub, which we *do stuff with*. Your comparison between GitHub and MDN seems no more fair than analagously arguing that questions are about *Git* are off-topic because they're about 'using a software application', and pointing out that we don't allow questions about, say, Microsoft Word.

Comment: @MarkAmery In your definition are questions about jsfiddle.net, ideone.com, sourceforge.net or jira on-topic?

Comment: This question and the accepted answer proves I'm wrong: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157888/what-site-is-good-for-github-questions

Comment: Related: [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6311/25936)

Answer (score 10):

The GitHub website is a tool used primarily (actually, I think it is used exclusively) by programmers. As such, it qualifies as 'a software tool commonly used by programmers' as enumerated in the list of criteria for an on-topic question in the Help Center's [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page.

So yes, it is on-topic here.

See the [MSE canonical answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157888/what-site-is-good-for-github-questions/157915#157915), by Stack Overflow's founder, Jeff Atwood:

> Generally, Stack Overflow is fine, but as random pointed out in his comment, it depends what is being asked:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github
>
> GitHub is certainly a tool commonly used by programmers, per the FAQ. I like to think one of the best ways to decide what to ask is to first observe what is being asked and answered well by the community.
>
> (This should also explain why things that are popular for the wrong reasons, that are opinion pieces rather than science, are deeply problematic at SE.)
>
> Since you specified
>
> > suppose it's a question about github-style docs, or repository organization
>
> That implies it could be opinion-y, or a bit too specific to GitHub's own peculiarities. ***Overall though GitHub is so overwhelmingly a programmer site that some opinion and/or specificity to GitHub is likely to be OK.***

(Emphasis mine). The person who invented this very Q&A network seemed to think GitHub clearly qualified as a programming tool 10 years ago when he wrote that answer, and GitHub hasn't really changed what it does or who it's for since then, so I don't see any reason why we should consider it any differently today.

Answer (score 2):

It should be closed for two reasons:

1. It is about a specific program, a web application, which Stack Overflow is not about. However, there is a programming exception—except that the functionality involved here has nothing really to do with programming. Finding a particular user's history is often interesting and useful, but I am hard pressed to imagine a situation in which it helps you solve a programming problem. The programming tool exception was really there in order to allow valid questions about how to, say, interpret debugging results and further see into how a program is (mis)behaving.
2. It is about a web application, which will change often and in an unversioned manner. Future users of Stack Overflow. will find that the information quickly becomes bad: as evidenced by the fact that the one answer to this question *is already wrong*. We can't even say, "For version x of GitHub this worked...". Meaning future users are still left poking around GitHub for the correct answer.

In the comments [this response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157888/what-site-is-good-for-github-questions/157915#157915) is cited. However, nothing in that response saves this question: it says that some specificity to GitHub is probably fine, for instance, but does not say any specific question merits saving. "It depends on what is being asked." Here, what is being asked is marginally useful at best, and subject to answer-rot.

Comment: You did read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157915/158100 ?

Comment: I did. However, I stand by the above; the functionality in question isn't really programming related. GitHub doesn't get to decide to offload their forum here, and the answer is now wrong, so even though it was well received it is now not useful. Of course, that is just my opinion, but I think it's in line with S.O. guidelines.

Comment: I tend to agree but does your point of view also holds for jsfiddle.net, ideone.com, sourceforge.net or jira, to name a few? Is it a case-by-case decision?

Comment: But you're asking about sites, not about questions. *This question* doesn't really relate to programming; usually specific-author histories are for determining things about the author, not the code. I would totally stand for keeping the question open if it was about managing a repo, or doing documentation, or anything that was actually about the code. As it is, the case for that is weak, and, again, the only answer is now wrong - the only useful part is about git and not github.

Comment: If you ask how to find related projects on SourceForge, or how to see forks of a jsFiddle, that would be the same as asking where to click on GitHub.com to show commits. And they would all be better on Web Apps, not SO. It depends on what the question is dealing with. @ren

Comment: A scenario where finding the commits for a current user helps with programming:  I start a new project tomorrow and I would love to see the commits from the person who's leading the team on that project before tomorrow so that I will program more effectively.

Comment: I agree that finding those commits will help you understand what has been programmed. But that problem is subtly different from a programming problem: the solution has nothing to do with programming but with how to use GitHub's web site. SO is therefore the wrong place to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming that my guess is accurate, I don't agree with the closevoters' logic. GitHub, like Git, is a tool used by programmers, and so questions about it are within the scope of StackOverflow just as much as questions about IDEs or about Git are. The fact that GitHub also happens to be a website doesn't seem to me like a significant factor.

Try substituting Stack Overflow itself for GitHub. Seems equally valid to me. So why do we need Meta at all, in that case?

Granted I disagree in the first place with broadening the scope to include questions about IDEs, installing libraries etc. (*Packaging* code is another matter, of course.) Stack Overflow decided to allow that stuff, so I'm overruled. But surely there's a line to be drawn somewhere. "It's a website" seems to me as good as any.

Aside from that, Github isn't actually involved in the *process of writing the code*. It's only used for *distributing and publicizing* code (and follow-on effects, such as discussion on issue trackers.) While version control is important, that's the part that's actually relevant to creating the code - and that part is done by Git itself.

Maybe we should have explicitly written in that latter part, at least. I'm sure there are plenty of "tools" (especially if we count websites) that are "commonly used by programmers", but don't have anything to do with writing code. Like, say, Markdown editors. Or "programmer humour" sites.

Comment: The site does not require that tools be used _to write code_ to be on-topic here, only that they be [_software tools commonly used by programmers_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which GitHub absolutely qualifies as. Also, for what it's worth; you _can_ literally write code _on_ GitHub; I have done it before.

Comment: yes, and I'm critiquing that policy in a *reductio ad absurdum* way.

Comment: That may be effective if the arguments you used weren't wrong. You cannot ignore the other aspects of the page linked in my comment. Questions also must be unique to software development and otherwise on-topic.

Comment: I took those aspects into consideration. Most questions that could plausibly be asked about GitHub **are not** unique to software development; they're specific to **using someone else's program**, i.e. tech support.

Comment: The problem is, tech support questions about software used by programmers is on-topic. Witness the topicality of questions asking what [the latest version of, say, C# is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c).

Comment: Git isn't involved in the process of writing the code, either.  I mean, you could always just use Subversion or CVS or Bazaar or GZIP; it doesn't *have* to be Git.  But all of those *are* tools that developers use during the course of writing their code, or administering their project.  So, with that, this would be on-topic.  I don't know how you could argue in one side that a tool (a-la Git) is on-topic, but a service that leverages that tool (a-la GitHub) *isn't*.  That's to say nothing of GitLab or other hosted Git solutions, cloud or local, managed or self-service.