# Is it on-topic to ask why a GitHub feature is not working as expected?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, scope

I found a possible issue with search in GitHub issues and wanted to post a question about it, but I am not sure is a valid question.

Question:

> I was trying to find an [issue](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular/issues/3880)that i created so i went to the project issues and in Filters typed my username:
>   In filters i typed my username: lalo-mx. The search generated was:  https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=lalo-mx
>   The issue that was looking for is not there.
>   To found the issue  I have to filter the issues with "author:lalo-mx". The search url is: https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=author%3Alalo-mx+
>   Why does the filter in issues in GitHub not works with the author in the first search?

Is it a valid question for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Related: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: In the duplicated question says that is not valid because we don't know the answer.My intention was to get feedback from the community about how the filter is supposed to work.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  Going to reopen this question because [the topicality of GitHub questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379596/1079354) is not a black-and-white decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best that you can hope for at this point is that [your question has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433230/in-github-is-there-a-way-to-search-for-pull-requests-created-by-any-author-from).

Getting an answer that explains *why* it behaves that way is outside the scope of the site itself.

Comment: I have not published the question or do you mean the meta question?

Comment: He means, @lalo, *if* you publish the question, the best case is it will get marked as a duplicate, instead of being closed as off-topic.